# How to add 2 button in magento's admin - System, Configuration?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have already added button in System, Configuration. I want one more button in that tool but not able to do so.

Now two button is displayed but problem is both is calling same function. Both button have same id. Can anyone please suggest?

In config.xml


    
        
            0.0.1
        
    
    
        
            
                Product_Price_Helper
            
        
        
            
                Product_Price_Block
            
        
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                        Product_Price
                    
                
            
        
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                        Lowest_Quality_Price
                    
                
            
        
    
    
        
            
                
                    Allow Everything
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                            Product Price Settings
                                        
                                        
                                            Lowest Price Settings

In system.xml

Update Price
                            button
                            productprice/adminhtml_system_config_form_button
                            21
                            1
                            1
                            1
                        
                        
                            Update Lowest Quality Price
                            button
                            productprice/adminhtml_system_config_form_button
                            22
                            1
                            1
                            1

Manage Product Price
            99999
        
    
    
        
            Update Price
            product
            text
            99999
            1
            1
            1
            
                
                    Tools
                    3
                    1
                    1
                    1

```
                    <button translate="label">
                        <label>Update Price</label>
                        <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
                        <frontend_model>productprice/adminhtml_system_config_form_button</frontend_model>
                        <sort_order>21</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </button>
                    <lowest_button translate="label">
                        <label>Update Lowest Quality Price</label>
                        <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
                        <frontend_model>productprice/adminhtml_system_config_form_button</frontend_model>
                        <sort_order>22</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </lowest_button>
                </fields>
            </tools>
        </groups>
    </productprice>
</sections>
```

Comment: please explain your question more in details like where you want to add button exactly and what you have tied so far

Comment: @ashish Is it possible to put <frontend_model>productprice/adminhtml_system_config_form_lowestqualitybutton</frontend_model> in system.xml file

Comment: yes, can you please post your system.xml i am not able to understand your question.

Comment: @AshishMadankar  have created 2 buttons but they have same id. I want to give different ids so that I can call different function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you system.xml as you are using same **frontend_model** for both buttons i.e. `<frontend_model>productprice/adminhtml_system_config_form_button</frontend_model>` thats why you are getting same function calling and same id for both button.

You need to use different **frontend_model** for two buttons and create the same at appropriate path.

For testing purpose put `<frontend_model>adminhtml/system_config_system_storage_media_synchronize</frontend_model>` as **frontend_model** for any one button and see if you are getting different ids or not.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I  added the same and got different ids for button. But now where to call my function?

Comment: Now I created Product\Price\Block\Adminhtml\System\Storage\Media\Synchronize.php. Is it correct?

Comment: no, for the above path you need to put model as `<frontend_model>productprice/adminhtml_system_storage_media_synchronize</frontend_model>`

Comment: I am getting below error   Fatal error: Class 'Product_Price_Block_Adminhtml_System_Storage_Me‌​dia_Synchronize' not found in app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 590

Comment: can you please put a newly created file path and content in question also place a full content of config.xml along with path their must be a path issue.

Comment: I have edited the question again and put config.xml files full content

Comment: not able to understand your code and i need  your Synchroni‌​ze.php files content along with path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44198/discussion-between-jassi-and-ashish-madankar).

Comment: How can I give you directly files?

Comment: please come to a chat

Comment: But how to come to chat?

Comment: click on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44198/discussion-between-jassi-and-ashish-madankar